# Issues with plotting the decision boundaries for the Iris Dataset with KNearestNeighbors

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to plot the decision boundaries for the KNeighborsClassifier in Scikit-learn for the Iris dataset. But, the graphs that I am getting don't make much sense to me.

[image]

I would expect the boundary between the dark blue and light blue lines go in the direction for the green line that I drew on the picture.

The code that I used to generate it can be found below. It was inspired by [Plot the decision boundaries of a VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_voting_decision_regions.html).

What am I missing or not understanding?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat May 30 14:22:05 2020

@author: KamKam

Plotting the decision boundaries for KNearestNeighbours.
"""
# Import required modules.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

n_neighbors = [1, 3, 9]

# Load the iris dataset.
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, 2:4] # Slice features to only contain 
y = iris.target


# Set up the data such that it can be inserting into one plot.
# Count the number of each target that are in the dataset.
ylen = y.shape[0]
unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

# Create empty arrays for each of the targets. We only require them to have 2
# features because we are only plotting in 2D.
X0 = np.zeros((counts[0], 2))
X1 = np.zeros((counts[1], 2))
X2 = np.zeros((counts[2], 2))

countX0, countX1, countX2 = 0, 0, 0 #Initialize place holder for interating
# though and adding data to the X arrays.
# Insert data into to newly created arrays.
for i in range(ylen):
    if y[i] == 0:
        X0[countX0, :] = X[i, :]
        countX0 += 1
    elif y[i] == 1:
        X1[countX1, :] = X[i, :]
        countX1 += 1
    else:
        X2[countX2, :] = X[i, :]
        countX2 += 1

h = 0.02 # Step size of the mesh.
plotCount = 0 # Counter for each of the plots that we will be creating.

# Create colour maps.
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['darkorange', 'c', 'darkblue'])

# Initialize plotting. Close all the currently open plots, initialize the 
# figure and subplot commands
plt.close('all')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
axs = axs.ravel()

for j in n_neighbors:
    # Create the instance od Neighbours classifier and fit the data.
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=j)
    knn.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color for each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max]
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), 
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = knn.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    axs[plotCount].pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_bold)

    # Plot the training points.
    axs[plotCount].scatter(X0[:,0], X0[:,1], c='k', marker='o', 
                           label=iris.target_names[0])
    axs[plotCount].scatter(X1[:,0], X1[:,1], c='r', marker='o', 
                           label=iris.target_names[1])
    axs[plotCount].scatter(X1[:,0], X2[:,1], c='y', marker='o', 
                           label=iris.target_names[2])
    axs[plotCount].set_xlabel('Petal Width')
    axs[plotCount].set_ylabel('Petal Length')
    axs[plotCount].legend()
    axs[plotCount].set_title('n_neighbours = ' + str(j))
    plotCount += 1

fig.suptitle('Petal Width vs Length')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The introduction of the arrays X0, X1 and X2 seems to complicate things too much and makes it hard to turn the code more pythonic.

Some things that should be avoided in Python:

- the superfluous variable `plotCount` only to iterate through the axes, can be left out and replaced by `for j, ax in zip(n_neighbors, axs)`.
- The contents for `X0`, `X1` and ``X2`can be obtained directly via`X[:, 0][y == y_val], X[:, 1][y == y_val]` which moreover allows to write the scatter plots easily in one loop. You can read more about numpy's advanced indexing in [this doc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

n_neighbors = [1, 3, 9]

# Load the iris dataset.
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, 2:4]  # Slice features to only contain
y = iris.target

# Set up the data such that it can be inserting into one plot.
# Count the number of each target that are in the dataset.
ylen = y.shape[0]
unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

h = 0.02  # Step size of the mesh.

# Create colour maps.
#cmap_light = ListedColormap(['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['darkorange', 'c', 'darkblue'])

# Initialize plotting. Close all the currently open plots, initialize the
# figure and subplot commands
plt.close('all')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
axs = axs.ravel()

for j, ax in zip(n_neighbors, axs):
    # Create the instance od Neighbours classifier and fit the data.
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=j)
    knn.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color for each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max]
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - h, X[:, 0].max() + h
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - h, X[:, 1].max() + h
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = knn.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_bold)

    # Plot the training points.
    for y_val, (color, name) in enumerate(zip(['k', 'r', 'y'], iris.target_names)):
        ax.scatter(X[:, 0][y == y_val], X[:, 1][y == y_val], c=color, marker='o', label=name)

    ax.set_xlabel('Petal Width')
    ax.set_ylabel('Petal Length')
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_title(f'n_neighbours = {j}')

fig.suptitle('Petal Width vs Length')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you @JohanC. It looks like I was plotting the decision boundary for the wrong data in the end. I will read the doc that you shared. The way that you made such a small change that made the code so much cleaner is awesome. All the best!